# Time Machine fails regularly (but not always)

Tags: backup, time-machine, usb, external-disk

I've got a [LaCie USB-C Mobile Drive](https://www.lacie.com/gb/en/products/mobile-drive/). It is attached to my 2019 15" MacBook Pro via the USB hub built into my Dell P2721Q monitor. (So the MBP gets power from the monitor via USB-C and that cable also transmits USB-C.)

I'm on macOS Big Sur 11.4 as I write this. The drive is formatted as an APFS Time Machine volume.

Every so often, but regularly, the time machine backup fails, and gives the message

> Time Machine couldn’t complete the backup to “Diamond”
>
> Unable to complete backup. An error occurred while creating the backup folder.

When it gets into this state, if I try to open the drive in finder, it actually (incorrectly) shows up empty, with 'Backups of ""' (i.e., no name) at the top of the window, and '0 items, 3.6 TB available' at the bottom. It is a 5GB drive and that amount shows what is actually left -- there is really about 1.4TB taken up with backups.

If I try to eject, it fails with a dialogue 'The disk "Diamond" wasn't ejected because one or more programs may be using it. You cam try to eject the disk again or click Force Eject to eject it immediately.' I think `lsof` doesn't show anything open on this volume (if I'm using it correctly). Force Eject does work, as does a reboot, and I can usually make some more backups. But eventually the problem resurfaces.

I have reformatted the disk, and it worked ok for a couple of weeks before the problem resurfaced. Since reformatting, I have successfully managed to never unplug the drive or hub before unmounting. (I was worried that might have been a problem -- but the problem came back anyway.)

(Perhaps relevantly, the USB hub occasionally gives me some issues -- if I unmount the volume, disconnect the computer, and reconnect, sometimes the drive doesn't show up, along with my webcam. Reboot solves this, as does sometimes a dance of opening the laptop, sleeping and waking, etc, but not in an easily-reproducible way. I don't know if this is related.)

Any ideas?

Comment: The USB hub in your monitor could indeed be the culprit... If you attach the drive directly to your MacBook Pro, do you have these issues?

Comment: I believe I had a similar problem and it was indeed due to the backup drive being connected through the monitor hub. I think it has something to with low power mode on the monitor which also switches off the USB hub after some time.

Comment: @X_841, yes, I was afraid and suspected that this might be the culprit, and hoped that there might be some sort of fix (since that was part of the point of getting a USB hub/monitor in the first place!)...